# Adding 2D parameters from WLS regression functions in statsmodels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, regression, statsmodels

I'm incrementally adding up the parameters of [WLS regression functions](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html) using statsmodels.

I have a 10x3 dataset X that I declared like this:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]])
```

This is my dataset, and I have a 10x2 `endog` vector that looks like this:

```
z =
[[  3.90311860e-322   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000  -2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000  -2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000  -2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000  -2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]]
```

Now after importing `import statsmodels.api as sm` I do this:

```
g = np.zeros([3, 2]) # g(x) is a function that will store the regression parameters
mod_wls = sm.WLS(z, X)
temp_g = mod_wls.fit()
print temp_g.params
```

And I get this output:

```
[[ -5.92878775e-323  -2.77777778e+000]
 [ -4.94065646e-324  -4.44444444e-001]
 [  4.94065646e-323   1.88888889e+000]]
```

Now the thing is, I need to incrementally add up the parameters. So I need to do is run `sm.WLS` in a loop, with a new endog vector each time, and store the fitted parameters in each iteration. I need to cumulatively add up the stored parameters to get a new regression function. My objective is to add them up in `g`.
For that, I've modified the above code to do this:

```
g = np.zeros([3, 2]) # g(x) is a function that will store the regression parameters
for j in range(m):     
    # some code to build a generate z vector
    mod_wls = sm.WLS(z, X) # each time this line is called, z has new values
    temp_g = mod_wls.fit()
    np.vstack((temp_g.params, g)) # append the parameters from temp_g to g
```

So this is what I'm doing.
I've actually run this before where the endog vector was a 1D array, and everything was fine.

But how to do this using a 2D array? When I print out the value of `g` and `temp_g`after appending `temp_g`'s parameters, this is the output:

```
g after stacking: 
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

So `g` doesn't seem to be adding on the rows of parameters from `temp_g`.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your forgot to assign `g=np.vstack((temp_g.params, g))` to update g

Comment: in general, appending and expanding numpy arrays is expensive because of memory copying. It's better to use lists and append, or create a large array first and then assign into a slice inside the loop.

Comment: BTW: OLS, WLS and similar are designed for a one-dimensional y, in your case `z`. `params` are estimated also for a 2-d `z`, but most of the other results will raise errors.

Comment: How do you mean "most of the other results will raise errors"? Do you suggest it better not to use the statsmodels WLS object with 2D endog arrays? I won't be going beyond 2D though.

Comment: see my answer to your next question `predict` fails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369859