# How to get the prediction of test from 2D parameters of WLS regression in statsmodels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, regression, statsmodels

I'm incrementally up the parameters of [WLS regression functions](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html) using statsmodels.

I have a 10x3 dataset X that I declared like this:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]])
```

This is my dataset, and I have a 10x2 `endog` vector that looks like this:

```
z =
[[  3.90311860e-322   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000  -2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000  -2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000  -2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000  -2.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000]]
```

Now after importing `import statsmodels.api as sm` I do this:

```
g = np.zeros([3, 2]) # g(x) is a function that will store the regression parameters
mod_wls = sm.WLS(z, X)
temp_g = mod_wls.fit()
print temp_g.params
```

And I get this output:

```
[[ -5.92878775e-323  -2.77777778e+000]
 [ -4.94065646e-324  -4.44444444e-001]
 [  4.94065646e-323   1.88888889e+000]]
```

Earlier, from [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248583/how-to-add-regression-functions-in-python-or-create-a-new-regression-function-f), I was able to predict the value of test data `X_test` using `numpy.dot`, like this:

```
np.dot(X_test, temp_g.params)
```

I understood that easily since it the endog vector, `y` was a 1D array. But how does it work when my endog vector, in this case, `z`, is 2D?
When I try the above line as was used in the 1D version, I get the following error:

```
   self._check_integrity()
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 247, in _check_integrity
    raise ValueError("endog and exog matrices are different sizes")
ValueError: endog and exog matrices are different sizes
```

Comment: @user333700 is it possible to use the parameters to build a new regression model and then just use the **predict()** function?

Answer (score 2):

`np.dot(X_test, temp_g.params)` should still work.

In some cases you need to check what the orientation of the matrices are, sometimes it's necessary to transpose

However `predict` and most other methods of the results will not work, because the model assumes that dependent variable, z, is 1D.

The question is again what you are trying to do?

If you want to independently fit columns of z, then iterate over it so each y is 1D.

`for y in z.T:  res = WLS(y, X).fit()`

`z.T` allows iteration over columns.

In other cases, we usually stack the model so that y is 1D and first part of it is `z[:,0]` and the second part of the column is `z[:,1]`. The design matrix or matrix of explanatory variables has to be expanded correspondingly.

Support for multivariate dependent variables is in the making for statsmodels but will still take some time to be ready.

Comment: OK I'll use `np.dot` then, since `fit()` does work with 2D arrays at the moment. But how about 2D weights? In the same way that I have a 10x2 `endog` array, I also need to supply `weights`, which is also a 10x2 array. But when I try `mod_wls = sm.WLS(z, X, weights)`, I get an error trace to: 
  `File "C:\...\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 405, in whiten... return np.sqrt(self.weights)[:,None]*X ...ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,1,2) (10,3)` What should I do to be able to use 2D weights?

Comment: iterate over columns of z and weights or stack them. That `OLS.fit` works for the parameter estimate is a side-effect of the implementation, it's **not** by design. 2D weights will never work without stacking or iteration over independent regressions, because we would have to transform the z and X array with each of the weight vectors.

Comment: But will fitting the model and generating parameters per column help to give a result from which I can construct the same thing I'd get if 2D arrays were supported directly? Can I confirm if this is exactly what you mean: (1) Get the parameters for all of the data `X` (which is 10x3), using only the 1st column each of `z` and `y` as 1D arrays. This will give a 3x1 array of parameters, `p1`. (2) Repeat the process for the 2nd column of `z` & `y`, & get another 3x1 array of parameters, `p2`. (3) Stack `p1` on `p2` to get `params`. Is this the same `params` I'd get if 2D arrays were supported?

Comment: Yes, it will give the same parameters if you assume the dependent variables are (conditionally) independent. You can try with OLS which should give you the same parameters. In general it will not be the case, because, when 2D dependent variables are supported, we will allow for dependence between the dependent variables. Instead of stacking in (3) you can also just predict in each individual model.

Comment: Alright I guess I'll do the iteration then. One more thing. My weights are 2D as well. Will `for y, w in z.T, weights.T: res = WLS(y, X, w).fit()` be fine?

Comment: Yes, except you need to `zip`: `for y, w in zip(z.T, weights.T): res = WLS(y, X, w).fit()` which iterates of the rows of the transposed arrays, i.e. columns of original arrays.

Comment: In such a case, (with 2D y and 2D weights), when I take **np.dot** then results are also with 2 values. What does this mean, conceptually? Is the array of two values actually just a "prediction score" for each class? (Given that each of the two columns in the weights and response vector refer to two different classes.)

Comment: If you have 2 response variables, then the prediction will be two values, one for each dependent variables. If your 2d dependent variable represent are two different classes levels of a binary choice variable, then it seems to me that you set up the problem and model in the wrong way.

Comment: oh dear... I've set it up here... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48992/compare-code-with-documented-algorithm-is-this-correct. Do you think you could take a look at it and see if it's as it ought to be?

Comment: Here is what I have, below. `g` is the 3D array holding the regression parameters. `test` is the observation whose class I want to predict, so I do `np.dot(test, g[j])`. These are the arrays below:
`g 
[[[  2.68368143e-01  -2.66696225e-01]
  [  3.71068380e-04   4.69110632e-05]
  [ -2.67626006e-01   2.66790047e-01]]
 [[ -2.68368143e-01   2.66696225e-01]
  [ -3.71068380e-04  -4.69110632e-05]
  [  2.67626006e-01  -2.66790047e-01]]]`
And the test observation: 
`[ 4.1  5.5  6. ]`. And the dot products:
`[[-0.50340578  0.50754377]
 [ 0.50340578 -0.50754377]]`

Comment: It looks to me like you really have to run separate WLS regression for each "class". There are too many loops for me to figure out what's going on in a reasonable amount of time. However, my impression is that WLS should have just one response variable inside the j loop. The j loop is already over the different columns of the response. Check your loops.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for that. Let's ignore my code - but specifically at step (2)(a)(i) on the algorithm image (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48992/gentleboost-for-multiclass-classification), doesn't the index [i][j] of the response **z** imply a 2D array, rather than a single response variable?

Comment: `i` indexes observations and you need all i for a single WLS regression, so you have one WLS regression for each "class" `j`. Also, my "impression" is that `g` are `fittedvalues`.

Comment: I've been using parameters... What's the difference between fittedvalues and parameters? Could I possibly just chat with you to clear out these confusions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52086/discussion-between-user961627-and-user333700)